# What's the oldest treaty still being enforced?

Tags: treaties

The title pretty much says it all. What is the oldest treaty (of any type) still being enforced between two political entities (i.e., nation-states, cities, etc.)?

Comment: Maybe the [Magna Carta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magna_Carta) (1215)?

Comment: If we are talking about international treaties, the Treaty of the Pyrenees signed in 1659 by Spain and France established borders between the two kingdoms that have not changed since then. It also established a condominium for a small island on the border, the Pheasant Island, which is still in force.

Comment: God's treaty with Noah not to destroy the world completely with a flood?

Comment: Could the Pact of Omar count?

Comment: @ClintEastwood: I'm going to disqualify Noah (treaties with supernatural/omnipotent beings seem rather hard to authenticate), but Pact of Umar/Omar seems like a possibility. Wikipedia suggests that it's authenticity isn't 100% solid, but given its supposed age (between 7th - 10th century) that seems understandable. I won't promise to accept it, but please add it as an answer.

Comment: Do religious rulings count? If so, then look up the First Ecumenical Council

Answer (score 25, accepted):

## Historical

### Both Parties Sovereign and Remain Sovereign

> [Anglo-Portuguese Alliance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anglo-Portuguese_Alliance) (or Aliança Luso-Britânica), ratified at the Treaty of Windsor in **1386**, between England (succeeded by the United Kingdom) and Portugal is the oldest alliance in the world that is still in force – with the earliest treaty dating back to the Anglo-Portuguese Treaty of **1373**.
>
> English aid to Portugal went back much further to the **1147** [Siege of Lisbon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siege_of_Lisbon).

### "Constitutional"

#### Sovereign Parties create a new Sovereign entity

> The [Federal Charter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Federal_Charter_of_1291) or Letter of Alliance documents the Eternal Alliance or League of the Three Forest Cantons, the union of three cantons in what is now central Switzerland. It is dated in early August **1291**.

One can argue that this document is *not* in force today, being superseded by many other documents defining [Switzerland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switzerland).

#### Between Sovereign and his Subjects

> [Magna Carta Libertatum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magna_Carta) (Medieval Latin for "the Great Charter of the Liberties"), commonly called Magna Carta, is a charter agreed to by King John of England at Runnymede, near Windsor, on 15 June **1215**.

It is hard to argue that it is still in force, because

> the original 1215 charter had concerned the medieval relationship between the monarch and the barons, rather than the rights of ordinary people, but the charter remained a powerful, iconic document, even after almost all of its content was repealed from the statute books in the 19th and 20th centuries.

### Neither Party Sovereign

> [Paréage of Andorra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Par%C3%A9age_of_Andorra_1278) was a feudal charter signed in Lleida on 8 September **1278**. It codified a lay and ecclesiastical agreement between the Count of Foix, Roger-Bernard III, and the Bishop of Urgell, Pere d'Urtx, establishing their joint sovereignty over the territory of Andorra.

### Intra-religious

The decisions of ...

> The [First Council of Nicaea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_Council_of_Nicaea) was a council of Christian bishops convened in the Bithynian city of Nicaea (now Iznik, Bursa province, Turkey) by the Roman Emperor Constantine I in AD **325**.

... are still binding on Christendom.

## Traditional

### Between People

> The [Pact of Umar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pact_of_Umar), is an apocryphal treaty between the Muslims and the Christians of either Syria, Mesopotamia or Jerusalem that later gained a canonical status in Islamic jurisprudence... attributed to **9th century** Mujtahids  ... the pact contains a list of rights and restrictions on non-Muslims (dhimmis).

I highly recommend a careful reading of the *long* list of the "rights and restrictions" (e.g., non-Muslims are not permitted any weapons and are required to wear a distinctive dress - [cf.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuremberg_Laws)).

Note that the current enforcement of the treaty is limited by [Edict of Gülhane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edict_of_G%C3%BClhane) and [Ottoman Reform Edict of 1856](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ottoman_Reform_Edict_of_1856).

### Between People and God

Covenant of Abraham, Isaac and Jacob with God (~3,500 years ago).
Still fully in force - see [Judaism.SE](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: and what about [Paréage of Andorra 1278](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Par%C3%A9age_of_Andorra_1278) ?

Comment: @Explorer: the signatories were not sovereigns.

Comment: Ok..I thought it can also be counted :-)

Comment: @Explorer: as you wish, see edit.

Comment: very nice. +1 for great efforts.

Comment: The 'Anglo-Portuguese Alliance' didn't work at all when, in 1890, the British sent an ultimatum to Lisbon, and thus forced the Portuguese withdrawal from present-day Zimbabwe... Not very friendly, that...

Comment: @xxavier: https://english.stackexchange.com/q/406124/30415 ;-)

Comment: The decisions of the Council of Nicaea are only binding on members of various Nicene denominations of Christianity and are not binding on members of various denominations which reject the decisions of the Council of Nicaea.  So it is not binding on all of Chrisitandom.

Comment: From https://www.legislation.gov.uk/aep/Edw1cc1929/25/9/contents the oldest act which still has parts in force is Magna Carta but not the original. It is the one relegislated in 1297

Comment: Great list, except for the last one. Let's be professional. The question states clearly "between two political entities". Sure the Church can act as a political entity, but certainly not any god.

Comment: In the strictest sense, the Abrahamic covenant isn't "apocryphal", since it's literally in the Bible and not the apocrypha.  ;-)

Comment: @James: you are not paying me enough to "be professional". ;-)

Comment: @MichaelSeifert: right, let's have a fight between religious and anti-religious zealots. Got popcorn? ;-)

Comment: @sds None of the 2 Apocryphal you list are actually Apocryphal. The correct word for the Pact of Umar is "inferred existence". It cannot be apocryphal because no text/direct source survives to be so. The Abrahamic covenent, even if considered a treaty, is also not aprocryphal, neither in the Christian/Jewish sense nor the general sense of the word.

Comment: @sds Religiosity has no place in standard, academic historical practice. As I'm aware, nowadays this is not up for debate. Would you post Alchemy formulas in chemistry Stackexchange? This downgrades history stackexachange quality.